# javascript hide table when enter invalid id in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Here is my c#:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();   {
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresult", con);

    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textstudentid.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textstudentid.Text.Trim());

    SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    com.Parameters.Add(retval);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string Output = retval.Value.ToString();
    output.Text = Output; 
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adp.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
        txttamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
        txtenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
        txtmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
        txtscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
        txtsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialScience"].ToString();
    }                
}
```

http://s8.postimg.org/n2unbqufp/untitled.jpg  <== output screenshot

And here is my aspx:

```
<table style="width: 60%;" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td> 
        <asp:Label ID="output" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>  

    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject Title</th>
            <th>Marks</th></tr>
          <tr>
             <td><asp:Label ID="lblt" runat="server" Text="Tamil"></asp:Label></td>           

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txttamil" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lble" runat="server" Text="English"></asp:Label></td>                

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtenglish" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblm" runat="server" Text="Maths"></asp:Label></td>               

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtmaths" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            <td><asp:Label ID="lbls" runat="server" Text="Science"></asp:Label></td>                

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtscience" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblss" runat="server" Text="socialscience"></asp:Label></td>                

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtsocialscience" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>
             <asp:Button ID="searchupdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="searchupdate_Click" OnClientClick="return update();" /></td>
     </tr>
       </table>
```

Finally storedprocedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_studentresult
(
    @id int,
    @output varchar(50) output,
    @id_student varchar(50)
)
AS

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=@id_student)
BEGIN
SET @output='Doesn not EXIST'
END
SELECT * from studentresult where id_student=@id
```

I have added search box above the table.. when i enter invalid id, and hit search, below displayed textboxes need to be hide. If i enter valid id and search then only it shows textboxes which are used for update and delete.

May i how to do that? I'm new to .net.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: How do you define invalid id? Is it invalid if input is non-numeric or numeric but still invalid when checked against database?

Comment: invalid means if the does not contains in student table means.. it will invalid id.. thanks..

Comment: Set `runat="server"` attribute on your `table` and `set table.Visible = false;` in `else` block of existing `if` condition.

Comment: @nvartak: If i enter valid id which is not having marks.. then i need to show table with empty text boxes..for insert score..